# XML into JSON conversion in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios6

I need to convert XML response to JSON.

My XML response:

```
<commands>
<command id="0" name="GetAPPsProducts">
  <command_parameters>
    <command_parameter id="0" name="APPs_Code">ATAiOS</command_parameter>
  </command_parameters>
  <command_result>
    <apps_products>
      <apps_products id="1">
        <apps_code>ATAiOS</apps_code>
        <apps_product_id>2</apps_product_id>
        <brand_id>2</brand_id>
        <brand_desc>Generic</brand_desc>
        <brand_product_id>2</brand_product_id>
        <product_id>001-7</product_id>
        <descrizione>MyTravelApp</descrizione>
      </apps_products>
    </apps_products>
  </command_result>
</command>
```

I am using XMLReader supporting file from this site:

[XMLReader](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/09/simple-xml-to-nsdictionary-converter/)

I am using this code to convert XML to JSON

```
NSError *parseError = nil;
NSDictionary *xmlDictionary = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:testXMLString error:&parseError];
NSLog(@" %@", xmlDictionary);
```

I got JSON response like this:

```
commands =         {
        command =             {
            "command_parameters" =                 {
                "command_parameter" =                     {
                    id = 0;
                    name = "APPs_Code";
                    text = "\n  \n    \n      \n        ATAiOS";
                };
                text = "\n      ";
            };
            "command_result" =                 {
                "apps_products" =                     {
                    "apps_products" =                         {
                        "apps_code" =                             {
                            text = "\n      \n        \n          \n            ATAiOS";
                        };
                        "apps_product_id" =                             {
                            text = "\n            2";
                        };
                        "brand_desc" =                             {
                            text = "\n            Generic";
                        };
                        "brand_id" =                             {
                            text = "\n            2";
                        };
                        "brand_product_id" =                             {
                            text = "\n            2";
                        };
                        descrizione =                             {
                            text = "\n            MyTravelApp";
                        };
                        id = 1;
                        "product_id" =                             {
                            text = "\n            001-7";
                        };
                        text = "\n          ";
                    };
                    text = "\n        ";
                };
                text = "\n      ";
            };
            id = 0;
            name = GetAPPsProducts;
            text = "\n    ";
        };
        text = "\n  ";
    };
    text = "\n  \n";
};
```

I need response like this:

```
  {
  "commands": {
    "command": {
      "-id": "0",
      "-name": "GetAPPsProducts",
      "command_parameters": {
        "command_parameter": {
          "-id": "0",
          "-name": "APPs_Code",
          "#text": "ATAiOS"
        }
      },
      "command_result": {
        "apps_products": {
          "apps_products": {
            "-id": "1",
            "apps_code": "ATAiOS",
            "apps_product_id": "2",
            "brand_id": "2",
            "brand_desc": "Generic",
            "brand_product_id": "2",
            "product_id": "001-7",
            "descrizione": "MyTravelApp"
          }
```

I get this response while conversion in online. How to get response like this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Its nothing but a dictionary representation, you can convert the data into dictionary after parsing value from xml, but question is why you will do this, because you will ultimately have to parse xml file, while to doing same thing twice.. ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convet XML string to JSON using iPhone sdk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354159/how-to-convet-xml-string-to-json-using-iphone-sdk)

Comment: Use @Ryan's Code , Working fine.

Answer (score 13):

```
NSError *parseError = nil;
NSDictionary *xmlDictionary = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:testXMLString error:&parseError];
NSLog(@" %@", xmlDictionary);
```

This code isn't converting anything to JSON. Its giving you an NSDictionary. You need to actually create the JSON data from the dictionary. Try this on for size.

```
NSError *error; 
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:xmlDictionary 
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted // Pass 0 if you don't care about the readability of the generated string
                                                     error:&error];

if (! jsonData) {
    NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
} else {
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@",jsonString);
}
```

Comment: I tested your Code , Working like a charm , Thanks for answering.

Comment: @RyanPoolos Im needing some help...Im getting this: `Code=-1016 "Expected content type {(
    "text/json",
    "application/json",
    "text/javascript"
)}, got text/xml" UserInfo=0x17f9e770 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://server.com/sw_icfs.asmx/Response_Sucursales?Cli_Cod=1&Key_String=hW9gvga8ieDBbM5wm4, NSLocalizedDescription=Expected content type {(
    "text/json",
    "application/json",
    "text/javascript"
)}, got text/xml}` any ideas? :)

Comment: you are handing XML to the JSON serializer. You need to use an XML parser instead.

Comment: @RyanPoolos thanks, how do I properly format this initial string for the xml parser? `-(void)parseXML{
    NSString *xmlString = @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\
    <string xmlns=\"http://server.com">\;
    
    NSData *xmlData = [xmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    
    NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xmlData];
    
    [xmlParser setDelegate:self];
    
    [xmlParser parse];
    
}`

Comment: Your problem is very different from this question. I think it best if you start your own question.