# Best way to display WordPress posts in xcode app?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, ios7, rss, xcode5

I am working on an app in which I would like to display the 5 most recent posts of my WordPress website. I would like to display the featured image, along with some preview text that will link to the post itself. I have looked in to directly linking the app to the database, and it seems ridiculously hard to do. Right now I'm thinking my best option is an RSS feed, but there are no tutorials for xcode 5 and iOS 7 that I could find. Is there a better/newer way to achieve this?

Comment: i would also like to do this, but for an area of a website that requires a login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using an RSS feed since Wordpress comes with an RSS feed ready to go. Then you can parse this XHTML data using JSON (JavaScript Object Notation), and use the data in your app. Here are some relevant links on JSON and using it in iOS7.

http://dadabeatnik.wordpress.com/2013/11/01/parsing-json-in-ios/

[XML into JSON conversion in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15811629/xml-into-json-conversion-in-ios)

Also, learning JSON on W3 Schools may not be a bad idea...

http://www.w3schools.com/json/

Good luck on the app!